# want to rename a file only for the first loop and for next loops need to delete last written file

Tags: file

I have a big text file called 'filename.txt'. I want to extract data from it and want to create the file with the same name (filename.txt). because i will be required to extract data from my main file for many time. 
How can I change a name of the main file to filename1.txt for the first time only, when i extract a data. so, that i can write a file with the name filename.txt. and to extract a data for the next loop from filename1.txt, I will be required to create a file with the name filename.txt. for that I will be required to delete the old file (filename.txt) first.

I am getting consfuse in it. 
how can i do it?

Comment: So you want to extract a subset of data from `filename.txt` and then write it to a new file called `filename.txt` but you also want to keep the original to use again later? Why not just rename the original file from the start and then you can call the smaller file `filename.txt` ?

Comment: Show the code you've tried.

Comment: Let say i will rename the file 'filename.txt' to 'filename1.txt' then it will create two types of the file and my original file will be 'filename1.txt', But, when again my loop will call this file it will try to rename the modified file 'filename.txt' and this will create an error.